# Add surrogate id key to keyless tables in legacy database; how might it affect business applications that talk to the database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, orm, advantage-database-server

I am asking this because we worked with legacy database all the time and it can be a problem with you try to put an ORM on a table without primary keys.  In this forum, many respondents to this problem have said (quite nonchalantly, in my opinion), just add a primary key to the table.  No big deal.

Now I am asking, if you suddenly add primary keys to tables in existing database, what possible negative effects can you imagine, especially to client application?  if the question is too broad, that pretty much already answer my question.

Comment: This can negatively affect the current business application in more ways than you can possibly imagine. Without a huge amount of details I'm unsure that anyone here can help much. That's why test services exist. Add the pks in your test DB, then see how the application breaks. Fix the application rather than removing the PKs as they come in handy as you're already noting.

Comment: I don't think the OP is asking us to imagine every way a new column can affect stupid application code. And this change really is no different than adding a column. The primary key constraint here is a red herring; it's automatically maintained by the dbms, which also guarantees uniqueness, and it doesn't affect the uniqueness of any existing or future rows (because currently there are *no* keys). Introducing a new column (at the *end* of a table) is just about the safest possible structural change you can make to an existing table. So, in a nutshell, I don't think this question is too broad.

Answer (score 2):

Before you start, make sure there's not some *other* mechanism in place to enforce uniqueness. For example, a `not null unique` declaration is behaviorally equivalent to a `primary key` declaration. There might be triggers; there might be privileges that require database updates to go through a stored procedure; there might be other mechanisms I haven't thought of this morning.

You seem to be talking about something like adding a column that's an autoincrementing integer, and declaring that to be the primary key.

Assuming that currently there really *is* no primary key, and assuming there's no other *equivalent* to a primary key, **the main issues involve application code that relies implicitly on either the order of columns or on the number of columns**.

For example, this is a valid SQL statement. You might find something like this embedded in application code.

```
select *
from your_table
order by 1 desc;
```

That statement will sort the result set in descending order by the values in the first column.

If you add a column to that table, and you position that column as the first column in the table definition, that SQL statement will start returning data in a different order than the other client expects.

Some platforms don't allow an `alter table` statement to change the order of columns; new columns go only at the end of the table definition. But even on those platforms, the DBA can dump data, rewrite the `create table` statement with the new column first, and reload the data.

This kind of issue--changing the number of columns in a table--can break some data imports and exports.

Insert statements written without column names, like `insert into foo values (...)` might fail.

Statements like these might also appear in triggers, but that's more a problem with database code than with application code.

There's some chance of performance issues. Using the new column as a clustered index--an option on some platforms--will change the physical order of rows. That will certainly *change* performance, but I can't predict whether that will certainly be a bad thing. The table will be wider--but not *much* wider--which means slightly fewer rows will fit on a page on disk.

**A resilient solution**

- Change the name of the existing table. (This is simple, but might not be easy.)
- Create an updatable view having the same structure and name as the original table.
- Change the structure of the original table.

All application code that used the name of the original table will now use the name of the updatable view instead. Since the view's structure and behavior are identical to the original table, all of the application code should just continue to work. (I'd be surprised if *application* code needed to know whether it was dealing with a table or a view, but that's a possible problem.)

**Precautions**

In any case, you shouldn't make this change in production *first*. You should make the change locally first, then in your test environment, and finally--when you've exhausted our collective imaginations--move to production.

And move to production a little at a time. Add the column, and wait a while. Populate the column, and wait a while. Repeat until done.

Comment: I will add that the process of adding the key could be lengthy if the table has a large number of records. This can be a real problem on prod. You also will have this key show up everywhere that you have used select * which may not be wanted. Views might need to be regenerated to include the column (in SQL Server even views that use select *). If you have insert statements, they may break if you did not specify column names. You may end up with some issues of repeating column names causing problems in reporting  if you call the field ID. Some triggers, data imports, or data exportsmay break.

Comment: I incorporated your comments, skipping only parts that were more about database code than about application code. Thanks.